# How can I travel from Toronto to Mumbai without needing a Transit Visa at layover and having an expired Canadian Visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas

What are different options to travel from Toronto to Mumbai without needing a Transit Visa at layover.
I am an Indian citizen and my Canadian visa has already expired.

Can you please help answering the question? Based on the [tweet](https://twitter.com/AirFranceIN/status/1388056641933746177) by Air France, I checked in the tool they suggested. But I could not interpret the information in a precise manner.

I am raising this question as I am exploring multiple airline options to travel from Toronto to Mumbai. I know that most of Schengen countries require Transit Visa. But there are other options like Dubai / Abu Dhabi. There also I am not sure if I require Transit Visa.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/), perhaps Turkish Airlines, stopping at Instanbul?

Comment: Doesn’t Air Canada fly direct between Toronto/Montreal and Delhi?  From Delhi you can continue to Mumbai.  Admittedly the fares are likely outrageous but it would solve your issue.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks. I could see some flights travelling with route Toronto -> Montreal -> Mumbai. Would this also require valid Canadian visa as the connection is domestic?

Comment: The flights are non-stop, either Toronto-Delhi or Montreal-Delhi depending on the day.

Comment: Flights from Canada to India fly almost directly over the North Pole. IMO it's one of the cheapest ways of getting to the North Pole, although you won't be seeing much of it... :-)